# How to post data from js client to golang server

Tags: javascript, rest, go

I want to create a simple rest api authorization service where js/html is client, golang is server and postgres is db. I had success posting body from postman and I received expected answer and data were added to db. But when I am trying to do the same from my js/html client the answer is null - `{"message":"Invalid request","status":false}`.

Here is my golang example code:

```
var CreateAccount = func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    account := &models.Account{}
    err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(account) //decode the request body into struct and failed if any error occur
    if err != nil {
        utils.Respond(w, utils.Message(false, "Invalid request"))
        return
    }

    resp := account.Create() //Create account
    utils.Respond(w, resp)
}
```

Client:

```js
'use strict'

const form = document.getElementById('form');
const url = "http://localhost:8080/api/user/login";


const myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const data = new FormData(form);

    let preparedData = JSON.stringify([...data].flat());
    console.log(preparedData)

    fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        body: data,
    })
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(result => console.log(result))
        .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>
    <title>Real Estate Moskow Hack</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header">

    </header>
    <!-- HEADER END -->
    
    <main class="main">

        <form action="http://localhost:8080/api/user/login" method="POST" id="form">

            <input class="email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Введите email">
            <input class="password" type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Введите пароль">
            <button class="button" type="submit">send data</button>
        </form>
        
    </main>
    <!-- MAIN END -->
    
    <footer class="footer">

    </footer>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please tell me where there might be a problem on a server or client and why?

Comment: Not sure how much it matters but you're not using the `myHeaders` in your `fetch`, at least not in the example code. To fix your problem you should use your browser's console to inspect the request sent by `fetch` and compare it to the request sent by postman, then eliminate any differences, and once you've done that you should be good (assuming you're handling CORS correctly).

Answer (score 0):

First of all you're sending `data` which is a **FormData** object, and not `preparedData` ( I guess you did stringify it to send it!).

Second if you decided to send `preparedData` it's not gonna work, because it's an array and your decoder was expecting an object (struct).
Make sure that the body you're sending matching the data type you expecting in your json decoder